# Is there any dependance with Red Hat using OpenShift

Tags: docker, openshift, redhat, devops

In my company, we are evaluating OpenShift as PaaS platform.

Beside the fact that Red Hat is a requirement to install OpenShift, is there any other dependance to Red Hat when deploying docker containers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two versions of OpenShift you should know about.

The first is OKD (previously known as OpenShift Origin). This is the upstream open source variant of OpenShift. You can install this on hosts running CentOS and Fedora. You don't need Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) to run it. Your images can use any Linux operating system. You are free to do whatever you want with OKD.

The second is OCP (OpenShift Container Platform). This is the Red Hat product version of OpenShift. It is the same code as OKD, but you get it via a product subscription from Red Hat, which includes support and product updates. OCP needs to be deployed on hosts which run RHEL. Your images can again use any Linux operating system, but if you want support for the operating system components in an image, you need to base your images on the RHEL base images you get via the subscription.

So your statement that Red Hat (presuming you mean RHEL), is a requirement to install OpenShift only applies to OCP. If you want to use upstream OKD, that isn't a requirement and you could use CentOS or Fedora as underlying host for nodes OpenShift is deployed to.

Comment: Very good answer ! Thanks! I guess we are talking of OCP. Can you detail what you mean by : "operating system components" ? I don't understand it well

Comment: If you build your own image, it is created from a base image. That base image might be CentOS, Fedora, Debian, Ubuntu, Alpine or RHEL. If you have OCP and use RHEL base image, then Red Hat also supports that base image and will provide updates to the base image to fix problems (eg security issues). If you use the others, you are on your own for the base image, or have to find someone else to support it for you.